# How to check if a string contains the non-breaking space character?

Tags: c#, html, unicode, string-comparison

I need to check whether a string contains non-breaking space, the character represented by `&nbsp;` which looks like regular space but is different.

In the following attempt, `subject` will contain something like "Hey 3", where the space between "Hey" and "3" is a non-breaking space character:

```
if (date != "" && from != "" && subject.ToLower().Contains("hey&nbsp"))
{
    ...
}
```

This code doesn't work as I want to match the actual Unicode character not literally "&nbsp".

How do I check if my `subject` string contains the non-breaking space character?

Answer (score 7):

NBSP stands for **Non-Breaking Space**. Unlike traditional space character, two or more consecutive NBSPs do not get collapsed to a single one.

HTML entity `&nbsp;` is actually translated to unicode character with code `00A0`. In C# you can write it like this: `\u00A0`.

So the string to search for becomes `"hey\\u00A0"`.
Using *literal string* feature of C# language. above string can be written as `@"hey\u00A0"`.

Comment: if (date != "" && from != "" && subject.ToLower().Contains(@"hey\u00A0"))
Written this way condition do not pass..

Comment: The best thing to do is to examine the string in debug mode, in order to see the exact characters the string is made of. Maybe there is some other space character between `hey` and `&nbsp;`.  
For example, HTML does not render normal spaces, tabulations and newlines.

Comment: String that we are trying to check for "hey\u000A" is actually subject of Email that app process. Maybe Gmail block such characters..

Comment: It should be "hey\u00A0" without the @ (I tried dumping the string literal in Linqpad with and without the @).

Comment: @trop_yes You could also consider a RegEx which would match "hey" followed by ANY whitespace character, which would get rid of any issues caused by Gmail changing the special character to a regular space (unlikely? more likely you just need to check for "hey\u000A" and it will work): new Regex(@"hey\s", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(subject).Success

Answer (score 2):

You can type in that char the contains

```
"hey 3".ToLower().Contains("hey\u00A0")
```

In which "hey 3" is actually "hey\u00A03"